# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY in Batch class. No error when done outside Batch

Tags: apex, batch, error, access

I have an odd issue where I am hoping its just something obvious that I am missing, so hoping to get another set of eyes on it.

I have a fairly simple batch class that is looking for CampaignMembers that were created a week ago or more, and haven't changed status yet.  Those that it finds, it updates the Status and reassigns the lead to a specific queue.

For the purpose of this, I simplified the code and broke it down to its core basic functionality.

```
public without sharing class JACampaignCleanUpBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {

    public static String DefaultSched = '0 00 00 * * ?';  //Every Day at Midnight 
    public static JA_Campaign_Clean_Up_Settings__c setting = JA_Campaign_Clean_Up_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();

    public final string query;

    public JACampaignCleanUpBatch() {

        Date sevenDaysAgo = system.today().addDays(-7);
        DateTime sevenDaysAgoDT = DateTime.newInstance(sevenDaysAgo.year(), sevenDaysAgo.month(), sevenDaysAgo.day());
        String sevenDaysAgoDTText = sevenDaysAgoDT.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'');
        query = 'Select Id, Status, Lead.Id, CreatedDate From CampaignMember Where ' +
                'Campaign.JA_Campaign__c = True And Status = \'' + setting.Status__c + '\' And ' +
                'CreatedDate <= ' + sevenDaysAgoDTText;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<CampaignMember> scope) {

        list<CampaignMember> members2Update  = new list<CampaignMember>();

        set<Id> leadIDs = new set<Id>();

        for(CampaignMember member : scope){
            member.Status = 'Not Contacted';
            if(member.LeadId != null){
                leadIDs.add(member.Lead.Id);
            }   
            members2Update.add(member);            
        }

        Group recycledQueue = [Select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' AND Name =: setting.Queue_Name__c LIMIT 1];

        list<Lead> leads = [Select Id, OwnerId From Lead Where Id In : leadIDs and isConverted = false];
        for(Lead l : leads){
            l.OwnerId = recycledQueue.Id;
        }

        update members2Update;  **//THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR**
        update leads;         
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        system.debug('JOB IS DONE!!');
    }
}
```

The issue that I run into is that I am getting access errors when running the batch.  I get an error like this

> First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   00v37000005jXdlAAE; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY,
>   insufficient access rights on object id: []

There error comes when trying to update the CampaignMember Status.  It's as if I don't have full access to the record.  SO then I tried using Apex Anon to update the member status like below

```
CampaignMember memb = [Select Id, Name, Status From CampaignMember Where Id = '00v37000005jXdlAAE'];
memb.Status = 'Not Contacted';
update memb;
```

No issue, no error.  So is there something I am doing in my batch?

Also worth noting that it works for a large majority of the CampaignMembers, it seems to only be tripped up on certain ones.  Can;t find a pattern though.

Lead Sharing is private but I am running as sys admin and apex runs in system context anyway.  The batch running user does have Marketing User permission set.  I am just stumped as to what the issue is.

Again, I am fully expecting (or hoping I guess) that this is something silly I am overlooking.  Just hoping you all can give me an extra set of eyes and tell me what I am doing wrong.

> **EDIT**

Based on some comments and answers, I removed the Lead portions and changed the class to literally just update Campaign Member statuses, and I am still getting the same behavior.

This is the simplified class that just updates statuses.

```
    public without sharing class JACampaignCleanUpBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {

        public static String DefaultSched = '0 00 00 * * ?';  //Every Day at Midnight 
        public static JA_Campaign_Clean_Up_Settings__c setting = JA_Campaign_Clean_Up_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();

        public final string query;

        public JACampaignCleanUpBatch() {

            Date sevenDaysAgo = system.today().addDays(-7);
            DateTime sevenDaysAgoDT = DateTime.newInstance(sevenDaysAgo.year(), sevenDaysAgo.month(), sevenDaysAgo.day());
            String sevenDaysAgoDTText = sevenDaysAgoDT.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'');
            query = 'Select Id, Status, Lead.Id, CreatedDate From CampaignMember Where ' +
                    'Campaign.JA_Campaign__c = True And Status = \'' + setting.Status__c + '\' And ' +
                    'CreatedDate <= ' + sevenDaysAgoDTText;
        }

        public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }

        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<CampaignMember> scope) {

            list<CampaignMember> members2Update  = new list<CampaignMember>();
            for(CampaignMember member : scope){
                member.Status = 'Not Contacted';
                members2Update.add(member);            
            }

            update members2Update;  **//THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR**      
        }

        public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
            system.debug('JOB IS DONE!!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming so, but just to be clear, does the user running the batch have `Marketing User` set?

Comment: Yes, I did check that.  The running user does have marketing user.

Comment: Figured it wouldn't be intermittent if that were the issue. Any triggers on `CampaignMember`? I can't imagine just resetting the status would cause that error. If it were encountered during the `Lead` reassignment it would make more sense.

Comment: what happens when you try via execute anonymous with exact Id thats failing like in error .The Id is "00v37000005jXdlAAE"

Comment: Mohith, that is what I am doing, I must have copied and pasted wrong.  I updated the question to reflect that.  Good catch

Comment: Some few things you may want to test with 1. Change the class to global to see if it makes any difference 2.Database.Batchable<SObject> explicitly use CampaignMember instead of Sobject .3.Separate Batachable from schedulable class .All these makes no sense but worth trying to see if any of these help

Comment: I tried the Database.Batchable<SObject> earlier and that didnt help, I will try the other two.  Shouldn't make a difference, but as you said,  its worth a shot, I am stumped.

Comment: It seems, perhaps, that [batches on CampaignMember](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131204/what-kind-of-actions-open-a-query-locator) are just subject to funny business.

Comment: Because it works fine in anonymous apex and fails in batch apex, May be something to do with api version of batch class??

Comment: Ok, so lots could be going on here. @ChrisDuncombe Did you adjust your batch query to only return the ONE record that is causing the error (since you know the ID). Set the logs to finest and sprinkle liberal debugs to see what is going on? Since you know the ID somethings a thorough log review with the batch acting on that one record will show the problem. OR it could actually work in which case you would at least know the error is misrepresented as being with that record. Could other code be causing the issue?

Comment: @Eric, so I did exactly what you suggested.  And the update worked!  So this lead me to start playing with the number of rows in the query, and it seems that it has to do with the number of rows returned in the query in the start method.  I took it a step further and just tried in Apex anon to query for 1000 campaign members, update the status of each, and it failed wth the same error message.  It seems that it has to do with mass updating CampaignMember records.  There are no triggers, or other code that I can see involved at all.  Its a pretty new and blank org.

Comment: @ChrisDuncombe - Glad I was able to help move this along, even it it is to yet another roadblock

Comment: I'm both sad and glad to report that I have been on the phone with Tier 1 and Tier 2 SF support today.  Neither could make heads or tails of it.  T3 tomorrow..... stay tuned

Comment: At least you're now getting to the root of your issue by having simplified your code. Can you reduce your batch processing size to say 150 or 100 records to see if that solves your issue? It sounds like you don't want to try updating all 1000 records at once in a single batch.

Comment: I tried just a batch size of 1, tried 50, 100, 150, 200 etc.  I feel like I am going nuts....lol.   Thanks for all the help though, it is much appreciated

Comment: Strange! Good luck with Tier 3. I'm confident they'll have some insights for you that are nuances we're unable to see. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that the code you're operating on isn't linking back to what you're primarily working with: `CampaignMember`. Instead, you're operating on `Lead` retrieved from CampaignMember without confirming that what's returned from your query is in sync with CampaignMember; instead expecting the results to apply to CampaignMember and the CampaignMember Ids that your QueryPointer is iterating on.

I recommend you refactor you code to something along the lines where the results of your query on Leads is synced with CampaignMember before you execute the statement `update members2Update;` It also may be as simple as moving the statement `update leads` to execute before the update on CampaignMembers statement.

In your code below, you're updating all CampaignMembers whether they're Leads or not. Do you have any that might be returned that are now Contacts that perhaps have an old LeadId associated with them? Those records wouldn't be returned in your query on Lead.

```
    for(CampaignMember member : scope){
        member.Status = 'Not Contacted'; 
        // 'Not Contactd' Status assigned regardless of whether lead or contact
        if(member.LeadId != null){
            leadIDs.add(member.Lead.Id);
            // could member now have a `contact.Id` if has been converted and lead.Id 
            // not removed from campaignmember record or some other system failure?
        }   
        members2Update.add(member);
        // ALL members are being updated whether lead or contact            
    }
```

It would seem important to test to see if `leads.size() = leadIds.size()`. If not, there would seem to be a higher likelihood for a potential with an issue to occur during the update on CampaignMember.

If they're not the same, then you'd seemingly want to add logic to remove the CampaignMember with the `LeadId` that's not in `leads` from `members2Update`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how any of that would cause an error.  What in this explanation could cause an error.  I get most of what you are saying, but none of it seems to add up to causing this error, unless I am misunderstanding.    I appreciate the time of looking it over for me, I just don't see how any of this would result in the error. 

P.S.  I tried to update leads first, as you suggested and that doesnt change anything, still get the error

Comment: I would look at the leadId that gave you the error but which you could update manually and see if any of what I've mentioned above applies or what might be different about that CampaignMember record compared to another in the same batch that was successful. The issue only seems to be related to leads from what you're telling us, but you're not matching them back up with CampaignMember, so something has to be out of sync. BTW, the without sharing would only apply to queries, not to crud FLS.

Comment: I don't think its related to leads at all.  I just commented out the lead portions, so no updates on leads at all.  Its just a simple batch that cycles through and updates campaign member statuses.  Still getting the error.  I think this has to do with mass updating campaignmembers.  I just cannot think of why though

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the above.